# react - useState never update the value

Tags: reactjs

I have this function component:

```
export default function Proximity (props){
  // const [center, setCenter] = useState([3.1397, 101.6852]);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(3.333);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(2.222);


useEffect(()=>{
      getLocation()
    },[])

function getLocation(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {

          console.log(pos.coords.latitude) // <-- 4.444
          console.log(pos.coords.longitude)// <-- 5.555

          setLat(pos.coords.latitude) ///<-- update lat value
          setLng(pos.coords.longitude) ///<-- update lng value

          console.log(lat) //<-- 3.333
          console.log(lng) //<-- 2.222
      });
    }

}
...
}
```

for some reasons, the `setLat` and `setLng` never update the value. `getLocation` is just one of the example. I have other functions also use `setLat` and `setLng`, when I get `lat` and `lng`, I always get back 3.333 and 2.222.

What seems to be the problem? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you update your code to include your JavaScript imports?

Answer (score 3):

`setLat` and `setLng` are async and you cannot log updated values just after setted. In this case you should use `useEffect` hook to log the latest values. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(lat);
}, [lat]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(lng);
}, [lng]);
```